# Can I store WordPress media in different sub-folders?

Tags: plugins, media-library

How can I have my media files saved in different sub-folders of my choosing in WordPress?

It just only use one folder for all media which make it hard to manage them.

Just to be clear, I'd rather not have my media organised by date and I have that option turned off.  What I'd like is to organise my media files by folders with names such as blogs & products.

Comment: Under *Settings > Media*, do you have *Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders* selected?

Comment: What "different folders" do you want? As @Milo notes, the month/year folders are built in. If you want anything different you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: I created new folders like blogs, products, ... but I cannot access their contents inside media library.

Comment: @Mil I want to made named categories.

Comment: Do you need folders or just categorisation for your media files?

Comment: @JohnnyPea I want all of files not reside in the same folder, since it will be hard to manage them. I want different folders so I can manage them much easily. But I don't know if there is better solutions (like categories you mentioned) or not?

Comment: By folders I mean real folders in your filesystem (visible on FTP etc.) but you can organise your media in (virtual) categories as you do with posts and other content. Like plugin Enhanced Media Library https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/ or Media Library Categories https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-media-library-categories/screenshots/.